# Javascript basic prototype - unable to update a property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, prototype, updates

I'm trying to create my first Javascript "prototype". It consists in creating a label placed on a google map V3, in which I'm writing thinks like "Loading the markers" during long operations.
However, I'd like to "reuse" my prototype and change the text which is written in. "Loading the markers" can become "Loading the shapes" during shape loading operation, etc...

Here is what I've written so far :

```
StateControl.prototype.text_ = null;

// Define setters and getters for this property
StateControl.prototype.getText = function () {
    return this.text_;
}

StateControl.prototype.setText = function (text) {
    this.text_ = text;
}

/** @constructor */
function StateControl(controlDiv, map, text) {

    var control = this;
    control.text_ = text;

    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

    // Set CSS for the control border
    var stateUI= document.createElement('div');
    //some css properties like stateUI.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    controlDiv.appendChild(stateUI);

    // Set CSS for the control interior
    var goHomeText = document.createElement('div');
    stateUI.id = 'stateControl';
    //some css properties like stateText.style.color = 'white';
    stateText.innerHTML = '<strong>' + this.text_ + '</strong>';
    stateUI.appendChild(stateText);
}
```

When I initialize my google map, I'm calling my prototype like this :

```
var stateControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var stateControl = new StateControl(stateControlDiv, map, "Loading the map");
stateControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(stateControlDiv);
```

and at the end of the init process, I fadeOut the StateControl with

```
$("#stateControl").fadeOut(3000);
```

**--- This works ---**

But now, I need to change the text of the `StateControl` when user clicks a radioButton called "Load the shapes". I'd like the `StateControl` `fadeIn()` immediatly with "Loading the shapes" as text, then `fadeOut(3000)` when shapes are loaded. I know how to use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, but I don't know how to change the text and "Loading the map" still appears when loading the shapes.

I tried with

```
homeControl = StateControl.prototype.setText("Loading the shapes");
```

in my `loadShapes()` method, but it only works if I create a new `StateControl` with the good text... But it's a waste and I just need to update `text_` property.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Did you try stateControl.setText("Loading the shapes"); ??

Comment: Yes I tried, and I have the following error in the console : `TypeError: stateControl.setText is not a function`

Comment: I post some answer, but it is just blindshot. Let me know, if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are confused with prototype stuff and also object creating in javascript. I will try to do short introduction.

In javascript, we sometimes use functions as constructors, same as you correctly did:

```
function StateControl(controlDiv, map, text) {
    // body
}
```

via constructors, you can make instances, with `new` keyword:

```
var myStateControl = new StateControl(stateControlDiv, map, "Loading the map");
```

In short, there are two ways, how add properties to instances. With `this` key word inside constructor or with `prototype` property of the constructor. The difference is very simple. Constructor is called each time you make a new instance, but the prototype has to be defined only once.

Important, prototype properties must be defined after constructor:

```
function StateControl(controlDiv, map, text) {
}

StateControl.prototype.getText = function () {
    return this.text_;
}

StateControl.prototype.setText = function (text) {
    this.text_ = text;
}
```

Since you define text in every instance, you dont have to bother with `StateControl.prototype.text_ = null;`.

I dont know how the rest of your code looks like, but try to change your approach a little. You need to change text in some html, so you need connection from instance to that html element. Also you have getter and setter, but instance properties are accessible without them...

```
function StateControl(controlDiv, map, text) {
    this.text_ = text;
    //so lets just make stateText as a property of this
    this.stateText = document.createElement('p');

    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

    // Set CSS for the control border
    var stateUI= document.createElement('div');
    //some css properties like stateUI.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    controlDiv.appendChild(stateUI);

    // Set CSS for the control interior
    var goHomeText = document.createElement('div');
    stateUI.id = 'stateControl';
    //some css properties like stateText.style.color = 'white';
    this.stateText.innerHTML = '<strong>' + this.text_ + '</strong>';
    stateUI.appendChild(this.stateText);
}

// and lets make method that will be able to change state text...
StateControl.prototype.setStateText = function (text) {
    this.text_ = text;
    this.stateText.innerHTML = '<strong>' + this.text_ + '</strong>';
};

// then somewhere in the code... 
$("#loadShapes").on("click", function() {
    stateControl.setStateText("Loading the shapes");
    $("#stateControl").fadeIn...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer ! However, I tried to put my constructor BEFORE my properties, then copy / paste your `setStateText` method and I have an error in the console : `Type Error : setStateText is not a function`.
Visual Studio doesn't seem like your `=` in  `StateControl.prototype.setStateText = function (text) {...}` and suggest me to use a `(`. I tried, but no result... Have you an idea ?

Comment: Lets try to put everything in jsfiddle, then we will se if it works.

Comment: Really hard to reproduce it in jsfiddle (will try it anyway). For information, I was inspired by https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom-state to create my prototype, even if my goal could be easier than in the sample.

Comment: I will try to reproduce just the part with messages... anyway it seems that you have a different kind of probblem. StateControl.prototype.setStateText = function (text) {...} is correct for sure...

Comment: Ok I reproduce it here :http://jsfiddle.net/L27yd/1/ But jQuery doesn't seems to work (`fadeIn` or `fadeOut` doesn't work in fiddle but are OK in my own project). Some code is missing in `changeText()`, I don't know what to write on here

Comment: great, let me just play with it for a while ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41198/discussion-between-windkiller-and-alexb)